# Dialect phrase "Dem aale Joos sing Fooß"

Tags: meaning, dialect

I'm reading "Der Bernsteinring" by Andrea Schacht, and there's already been at least one Kölsch phrase ("ene jode Frönd" - took a little bit of research), but I'm not sure about this one. That is to say, I can figure out the meaning (based on the context) - "The foot belongs to old Joos". Is this about right? Except as far as I've been able to find, "old"/"alt" is "ahl". Is by any chance variation possible because Kölsch isn't standardized? In short, what's up with this phrase?

Comment: "Dem alten Joo(Joos?) sein Fuß" one would say in Hochdeutsch I assume. Which means "Der Fuß des alten Joo (Joos)".

Comment: Oh, yes, it's "Joos", not "Joo". Got confused for some reason. Also with "sein" for "sing" the phrase makes much more sense (than with my original idea that it's "ist").

Comment: Please note I'm not familiar with "Kölsch" therefore I assume this is the meaning!

Comment: I'd translate this to "Des alten Jooses Fuss".

Comment: In Kölsch "ein/e" commonly becomes "ing", like in "Ming Sching sing fot  " :-)

Comment: I reckon that could go into an answer. And I can't figure out what that last sentence is supposed to be. I make the appropriate substitutions, but what does "fot" mean?

Comment: Is _Joos_ also the dialect form of _Josef_, similar to _Jupp_, _Sepp_ etc? Weird dialect, just like the beer! ;) ;)

Comment: "fot" in fact should have been "fott" (short "o"), which comes from "fort" which is something like "weg", "verschwunden".

Comment: "Joos" is still a common name in Dutch, BTW. And yes, it might origin from "Josef".

Comment: "Sepp" is more common in the dialects in the southern german speaking regions, where as "Jupp" is from the Aachen-Köln-Ruhrgebiet region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Des alten Joos' Fuß
```

ist die richtige Übersetzung.

> Is by any chance variation possible because Kölsch isn't standardized?

Ja, Kölsch ist, wie andere Dialekte, schlicht keine Schriftsprache. Wenn es in Ausnahmefällen doch schriftlich fixiert wird, schreibt jeder, wie er will, natürlich in einer Form, die zur Aussprache passt.

Comment: Ist das Apostroph da am Ende von "Joss" korrekt? Ich dachte die Dinger gibt's im Schriftdeutschen nicht? ;) Ich sag ja auch nicht: "Des Haus' Dach." Oder?

Comment: @alk: Du meinst, Apostrophe gibt es nicht im Schriftdeutschen, sondern nur mündlich? Oder gestisch (Schreinemakers)?

Comment: Ja, ich hab mal gelernt, dass es die nur in der wörtlichen Rede gibt. Wie ich "sagte" "*Die gib's im Schriftdeutschen nich'.*" ;-)